# detect outline of a object and handle the values within the outline

Tags: python, image, opencv, outline

Currently, I'm working with some images and would like to calculate, for example, gray value, area of the pixel, etc.
To do that I need to first detect the object from the image.

I tried:

```
img = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
edged = cv2.Canny(img, lower, upper)
```

But it detects all the edges of the object. I only like to detect the outline of the object (like the picture below, red line).[image]

Is there any way to detect the outline of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the GRIP software to implement an imaging processing pipeline to do this (which I have already done for you).
[image: Processing Pipeline]

**My image processing is as follows:** 
Original image: 
[image: Original_Cat]

1. Perform median filter blur (to smooth out edges of cat's fur)
   [image: Blurred_Cat]
2. Perform HSV Threshold on image (to create a mask that removes the white around the cat)
   [image: HSV_Thresh_Cat]
3. Apply the mask from step 2 to get the pixel values from the original cat image
   [image: Masked_Cat]

**Now using the image from that mask, you can calculate your grey values and pixel areas**

**Here is the [link](https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP/releases/tag/v1.5.2) to download the GRIP software**

**Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ORJLOiM3ITuIaBuxmxUmqNDUpZZbzBBY?usp=sharing) to all my files (including the auto-generated Python image processing pipeline)**

Comment: So I missed one step. Blurring the image. I guess that's the reason why my code detected all edges not the outline of the image. Thanks, I will try this method.

Comment: @Dong-gyunKim Let me know if it works, and if it does please upvote :)

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use other programs than python. Basically your answer isn't that helpful to me.

Comment: @Dong-gyunKim I attached the Python code via the second link. You don’t need to use the other program, just download the file from from that link